# Can't install Realtek RTL8188EUS drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN722N v3

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek, adapter, tp-link

I recently bought a Wireless USB Adapter TP-LINK TL-WN722N v3 (https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N). At first, it seems to work but I've noticed that there were, in fact, some problems with drivers after all. So I decided to install one, in following way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

When that didn't work I followed this [guide](https://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=11261.0):

```
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -v ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu/rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

But it gave me 'modprobe 8188eu - Exec' format error on the last command. I've also tried using dkms, but that does not seem to work either.

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

I'm running: Linux version 4.4.0-116-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-021) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #140-Ubuntu SMP

Right now the device is not recognised in any way after connecting it to USB port. How can I make it running?

Answer (score 0):

I have the official tplink page, but I haven't tried it.
The driver source can be downloaded on
[driver folder](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180521/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series7_beta.zip).

A pdf installation instruction can be found on this [link](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180508/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf).

please let me know